# Passing array or nested objects in body of request npm

Tags: node.js, request

I have to send some parameters of String type along with one array in my body.
But it throws me an error message:

> First argument must be String or buffer

Here is my code:

```
var tokenList = JSON.parse(req.body.tokenList);
    var mobParams = {
        "tokens": tokenList,
        "profile": "<myprofile>",
        "notification": {
            "title": req.body.title,
            "message": req.body.text
        }
    };

     request({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications',
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": "Bearer ********"
        },

        body: (mobParams)

     }, function(error, response, body){
        console.log('Ionic push error', error);
        console.log('IOnic push res', response);
        console.log('IOnic push body', body);
        if(!error){
            return res.send({
                code: 1,
                message: "success"
            });
        }else{
            return res.send({
               code: 0,
                message: error
            });
        }
```

How can I pass my array inside this object to request npm?

Also, I would like to add that this implementation works pretty fine through front-end but I have separate codebase which requires me to hit multiple FCM requests i.e. in a loop. So I would be happy to have a solution as neither ionic push nor FCM push works

For the FCM push I am trying the code below :

```
let desktopParams = {
                                        "notification": {
                                            "title": 'Merchant Portal Notifications',
                                            "body": req.body.text
                                            // "click_action" : action
                                        },
                                        "to": '/topics/' + topic
                                    };
                                     request({
                                        method: "POST",
                                        json: true,
                                        url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
                                        headers: {
                                            "content-type": "application/json",
                                            "authorization": "key=****"
                                        },
                                        body: desktopParams
                                    }, function(error, response, body){
                    console.log('error', error);
                    console.log('response', response);
                    console.log('body', body);


                                        //return body;
                                    });
```

Comment: Try `body: JSON.stringify(mobParams)`

Comment: Tried. Call doesn't resolve. No errors , nothing on console.

Comment: add `"Content-Length":JSON.stringify(mobParams).length` in request headers

Comment: Didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

you should try stringifying your `tokenList` & `req.body.text` before you join it with with the string (try to log it and post the outcome so that people will have a better idea about the objects...):

---

```
var cho = [{name:'john',lname:'cena'},{name:'mary',lname:'jane'}];
var che = {list:[{name:'john',lname:'cena'},{name:'mary',lname:'jane'}],group:'people'}


var mobParams = {
        "tokens":JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cho)),
        "profile": "<myprofile>",
        "notification": {
            "title": "Some title",
            "message":JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(che))
        }
    };


console.log(JSON.stringify(mobParams));//----->{"tokens":[{"name":"john","lname":"cena"},{"name":"mary","lname":"jane"}],"profile":"<myprofile>","notification":{"title":"Some title","message":{"list":[{"name":"john","lname":"cena"},{"name":"mary","lname":"jane"}],"group":"people"}}}
```

---

```
var arr = [{name:'john',lname:'cena'},{name:'mary',lname:'jane'}]
```

---

```
var js = JSON.stringify(arr);
var blabla = {'item':'something',js}
console.log(blabla); //-----> Object {item: "something", js: "[{"name":"john","lname":"cena"},{"name":"mary","lname":"jane"}]"}
```

---

```
var js = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
var blabla = {'item':'something',js}
console.log(blabla); //-----> Object {item: "something", js: Array(2)}
```

---

```
var js = JSON.parse(arr);
var blabla = {'item':'something',js}
console.log(blabla); //-----> "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
```

---